# Text without a frame

Tags: python, user-interface, pycharm

What can I modify so that I just display my text without the frame on a window created in PyCharm ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaUNY.jpg)

```
label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, text="I want a text without a frame, and the frame reflects the wallpaper", font=('Century Gothic', 20))
label.place(x=50, y=50)
```

I tried this code it didn't work !

```
# Set app background to transparent (this might not work as expected with customtkinter)
app.attributes("-transparentcolor", "grey");

# Creation of the label without visible frame
label = ctk.CTkLabel(app, text="I want a text without a frame, and the frame reflects the wallpaper", font=('Century Gothic', 20), fg="white", bg="grey");

label.place(x=50, y=50);

app.mainloop()
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Change it to:  label = ctk.CTkLabel(app, text="I want a text without a frame, and the frame reflects the wallpaper", font=('Century Gothic', 20), borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
By adding borderwidth=0 and highlightthickness=0, you ensure that the label widget does not have a visible frame.

Comment: thank you for the tip, I haven't found a method as simple as yours, but by adding what you just told me I have an error,  
```
ValueError: ['borderwidth', 'highlightthickness'] are not supported arguments. Look at the documentation for supported arguments.
```  https://imgur.com/QOPoAPU